# Can't convert a string with a point to a double

Tags: excel, vba

I have the problem, that if I try to convert e.g. "10.5" to a double via CDbl(), it becomes 105 instead of 10.5. I searched for an answer for nearly half an hour now and can't find anything. Am I doing a mistake or is it just the way CDbl works?

```
Private Sub btn_Enter_Click()
    number2 = CDbl(Output)
    Select Case operator
        Case "+"
            Output = number1 + number2
        Case "-"
            Output = number1 - number2
        Case "*"
            Output = number1 * number2
        Case "/"
            Output = number1 / number2
    End Select
    operator = ""
End Sub
```

```
number1 = 10
Output (before it gets converted to number2) = "2.5"
operator = "*"

What I should get:
25

What I get:
250
```

PS: If you wonder why I don't use Application.Evaluate for the operator, my teacher wants me to use a Select Case

Comment: What is the result of the following line: `MsgBox Application.DecimalSeparator`? If it is a comma (`,`), then you will have to `Replace` the dot (`.`) with it before you do the `CDbl`.

Comment: Your teacher is not very good if they are allowing you to use variables without declaring them.  Please update your code to show the declaration for output, number1 and number2

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you, I have to use a comma instead of a dot.

Comment: @freeflow number1 and number2 are both public variables 
`Option Explicit`
    `Public number1 As Double`
    `Public number2 As Double`
Output is a label. With Output = "Example" you change the caption of the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*CDbl* assumes the *local decimal separator* to be present, probably *comma* in your case.

Use *Val* when the decimal point is known to be a dot:

```
number2 = Val(Output)
```

Comment: With a _local decimal separtor_ of _dot_, Val("2,5") evaluates to 2.  Assuming similar behavior on the OP's computer, this doesn't produce the result they desire.

Comment: @BrianMStafford: Read again, please. The questioneer has the value for `output` as `"10.5"`, not `"10,5"`.

Comment: The [Val function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) page on *Microsoft Docs* contains the following: *"The Val function recognizes only the period ( . ) as a valid decimal separator. When different decimal separators are used, as in international applications, use CDbl instead to convert a string to a number."*

Comment: Thank you, I actually had to use a comma. Weird though, because when I first tested it, I got an error.